# Why doesn't bootstrap accordion show content on click?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to web development and am working on my first website. I'm having issues implementing  an accordion style card in my webpage. It currently allows me to click on the different title but, the collapsed ones won't expand to show me the descriptions inside. Any idea where I'm going wrong and how I can fix it.

[image: Current card table]

```
<div class="col col-sm order-sm-first col-md">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
                   
                <div class="accordian">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="peterhead">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#peter">
                                Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse show" id="peter" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents who undertook the arduous journey
                                    to the shores of America with the intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's
                                    wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes with whatever is available inexpensively at
                                    the supermarket, was his first inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which
                                    <em>The Frying Pan</em> became well known. He brings his zeal for fusion cuisines to this restaurant,
                                    pioneering cross-cultural culinary connections.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="dannyhead">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">
                                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#danny">
                                Dhanasekaran Witherspoon <small>Chief Food Officer</small>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="danny" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his colleagues, comes from a long established
                                    family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback
                                    gave him great appreciation for varieties of food sources. As he puts it in his own words,
                                    <em>Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays, pays!</em></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="agumbehead">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">
                                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#agumbe">
                                Agumbe Tang <small>Chief Taste Officer</small>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="agumbe" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Blessed with the most discerning gustatory sense, Agumbe, our CTO, personally ensures that every dish
                                    that we serve meets his exacting tastes. Our chefs dread the tongue lashing that ensues if their
                                    dish does not meet his exacting standards. He lives by his motto,
                                    <em>You click only if you survive my lick.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="albertohead">
                            <h3 class="mb-0">
                                <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#alberto">
                                Alberto Somayya <small>Executive Chef</small>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="alberto" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with
                                    whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences.
                                    He says,
                                    <em>Put together the cuisines from the two craziest cultures, and you get a winning hit! Amma Mia!</em></em></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes were all mixed up and didn't match between the headers and the bodies they were supposed to be opening.

Take a look at this:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Corporate Leadership</h2>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#peter">
          <h3>Peter Pan <small>Chief Epicurious Officer</small></h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="peter" class="collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes
          with whatever is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which The Frying Pan became well known. He brings his zeal for fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural
          culinary connections.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#danny">
          <h3>Dhanasekaran Witherspoon <small>Chief Food Officer</small></h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="danny" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his colleagues, comes from a long established family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback gave him great appreciation for varieties
            of food sources. As he puts it in his own words, <em>Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays, pays!</em>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#agumbe">
          <h3>Agumbe Tang <small>Chief Taste Officer</small></h3>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="agumbe" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Blessed with the most discerning gustatory sense, Agumbe, our CTO, personally ensures that every dish that we serve meets his exacting tastes. Our chefs dread the tongue lashing that ensues if their dish does not meet his exacting standards.
            He lives by his motto, <em>You click only if you survive my lick.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a class="collapsed btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#alberto">
        <h3>Alberto Somayya <small>Executive Chef</small></h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="alberto" class="collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. He says, <em>Put together the cuisines from the two craziest cultures, and you get a winning hit! Amma Mia!</em>

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the code snippet you sent, and its improved the look of the card, but for some reason the collapsed items still aren't opening up on the webpage.

Comment: Where are you placing your JavaScript in the DOM?

Comment: I tried adding your script to the code and it ended up running, thanks!